# How does one cycle back to previous options in a C# console application?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm working on a short text adventure as a learning experience. I'm trying to make a dialogue system where the player can choose three dialogue options:

1. Player says something -> NPC responds -> Player responds to NPC's response -> NPC responds again -> options cycle back to the three initial dialogue options
2. Player says something -> NPC responds -> options cycle back to the three initial dialogue options
3. Player ends dialogue -> options return to main dialogue options (which encases the following code)

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
            //Talk to Smith
            if (Input == "TALK TO SMITH")
            {
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Initial discussion and character introduction");
                    Console.WriteLine("(Enter the corresponding number with what you want to say)");
                    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to discuss with Smith?");
                }
                do
                {
                    correct = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("1. Dialogue Option #1");
                    Console.WriteLine("2. Dialogue Option #2");
                    Console.WriteLine("3. Dialogue Option #3");
                    Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                    if (Input == "1")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        dialogue = 1;
                        correct = 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Dialogue Option #1");
                        Console.WriteLine("Response #1");
                        Console.WriteLine("1. Dialogue Option #1A");
                        Console.WriteLine("2. Dialogue Option #1B");
                        Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                        do
                        {
                            if (Input == "1")
                            {
                                dialogue = 0;
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("Dialogue Option #1A");
                                Console.WriteLine("Response #1A");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                correct = 1;
                            }
                            if (Input == "2")
                            {
                                dialogue = 0;
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("Dialogue Option #1B");
                                Console.WriteLine("Response #1B");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                correct = 1;
                            }
                        
            } while (correct == 1 && dialogue == 0);
                    }
                    if (Input == "2" && dialogue == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        dialogue = 1;
                        correct = 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Response #2");
                        Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    }
                    if (Input == "3")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        dialogue = 1;
                        correct = 0;
                        Console.WriteLine("Response #3");
                        Input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    }
                } while (correct == 1 && location == 1);
             }
```

(This is only a part of the game's code, not the entire program itself)

The issue is that once I've chosen options #1A, #1B, or #2 the program does not cycle back to the dialogue with the NPC, but the main menu that I've set up. I've tried multiple methods, but none seem to work.

Comment: Some more constructive advice than rwong gave: The first few times I tried to build a game, I did what you're doing, trying to code all the content directly into the source code.  What I learned is that that becomes an unmanageable mess very quickly. There's a better way, *especially* for a story-heavy game like you're doing: your source code should *describe the basic rules*, and then the content should go in data files, with scripts to handle special-case logic that doesn't belong in the main source code. Doing the game source this way is called a "game engine," and it's much more effective.

Comment: if you are more interested in making the game rather than the game engine you might try http://inform7.com/

Answer (score 7):

There's actually a formal concept in Computer Science that maps very well to what you're trying to do: a [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

The idea of a Finite State Machine is that it's a system that has a finite number of States that it can be in, the system is always in exactly one State, and each State contains a certain number of defined Transitions that put the system into a new State.

Dialogue trees are a very good fit for the FSM concept.  The initial State of the system is the start of the dialogue, and each of the player's possible responses cause a Transition to a new State.  It helps to formally model it like this:

```
State 0:
   MessageBox(NPC001, "Is there anything else you need to know?")
   Response "Where is the castle located?":
      GotoState 1
   Response "What sort of defenses does the castle have?":
      GotoState 2
   Response "Are we sure the Princess is being held in this castle?":
      GotoState 3
   Response "No, I think that's all.":
      GotoState 4
State 1:
   MessageBox(NPC001, "It is located two days' journey to the north, on the other side of the Dark Forest")
   GotoState 0
State 2:
   MessageBox(NPC001, "The castle is defended by monsters conjured forth by the Sorcerer King.  Be sure to bring plenty of healing potions!")
   GotoState 0
State 3:
   MessageBox(NPC001, "Of course!  What do you think this is, a Mario game?")
   GotoState 0
State 4:
   MessageBox(NPC001, "Farewell, heroes. May the Gods be with you on your journey!")
   //no state transition here, so execution of the state machine ends at this point
```

Translating this outline into actual C# code is left as an exercise to the reader, but the basic idea is that each State is a method on the state machine object, and it continues running one method after another until it executes a method that does not end up telling it what the next State should be.  (If you were using [Boo](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/), you could define a state machine macro and the outline above could *literally be the code of your dialogue tree,* but that's a whole other matter.)

Do a bit of research on the theory behind how a Finite State Machine works, and you'll find implementing things like this gets a whole lot easier.

## EDIT:

Here's one way to implement a FSM for something like this.

```
class DialogueTree {
   public void Execute()
   {
      int state = 0;
      while (state >= 0)
      {
         switch (state)
         {
            case 0:
               state = this.State0();
               break;
            case 1:
               state = this.State1();
               break;
            //and so on
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Each method would display some dialogue and choices, and return the next state for the state machine to go into based on the choice the player makes.  To exit the conversation, a method should return -1.  Does that help?

Remember, this is one possible way to do it.  There are other implementations, some of which can be better or worse for certain applications of the State Machine concept.

Comment: Thank-you very much for the response. I've done some digging around, and I can't seem to find anything on the application of Finite State Machines in text adventure dialogue. In general, the topic seems too advanced for my current level of understanding. Unfortunately, I'm too new to code to properly translate what you wrote into C#.

Comment: @PlzHelp: I edited it to give a bit more of an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

It would require a restructuring of code, in particular to change the "linear" or "if then else" flow into a "display - response" loop.

The next dialog to be shown is captured in a state variable.

In each "display - response" cycle,

- A prompt is displayed;
- User response is captured;
- Changes to program states are made, in order to encode the "knowledge" into the "story line";
- The next dialog is chosen.

A simplified sketch of the code would look like this:

```
/// somewhere else
enum NextDialog
{
    Smith,
    Anderson,
    Finished
}

NextDialog nextDialog = NextDialog.Smith;

while (nextDialog != NextDialog.Finished)
{
    NextDialog nextNextDialog;
    switch (nextDialog)
    {
    case NextDialog.Smith:
        // Each handler is responsible for:
        // (1) printing the prompt
        // (2) getting the user response
        // (3) converting the user response into state (program variable) changes, as well as determine the next dialog.
        // Each handler will need access to object fields;
        // these typically do not appear on the arguments list because
        // all instance methods can access all object fields.
        nextNextDialog = ProcessDialogSmith( ... ); 
        break;
    case NextDialog.Anderson:
        nextNextDialog = ProcessDialogAnderson( ... );
        break;
    default:
        throw new UnhandledException();
    }
    nextDialog = nextNextDialog;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for the response, but unfortunately I'm too new to coding to really grasp what you're saying here. I don't think I can make use of this method at my level.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "goto", it works very well. It helped me lots with as little code as possible
For example:

```
Choice1:
Console.WriteLine("This is your  choice. Make it now.")
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if (answer = "1")
{
Console.WriteLine("This is the wrong choice. Guess again.");
goto Choice1;
}
else //obviously it's an else if, but it's just an example so we use an else
{
Console.WriteLine("Oh wonderful! You made the right choice.");
}
```

Comment: _"you can just use "goto""_ - you can but generally you should not.